# Unable to use virt-sysprep on libvirt/qemu virtual machine on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to run virt-sysprep on a qemu virtual machine on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried the following commands: `virt-sysprep --format=qcow2 -a /var/lib/libvirt/images/Debian10-1.qcow2` and `virt-sysprep -d debian10-1`

The virtual machine is off. I have tried changing permissions and ownership of the image. I have searched the internet for segments of the error message and did not find a solution. I searched libguestfs.org for matches and found nothing relevant.

[Here is the complete output with debugging info.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tptHJMS57J/)

Comment: This a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1458711/1680405) which doesn't require root privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required to run `sudo chmod 0644 /boot/vmlinuz*` on Ubuntu. More information [here](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#binaries)